# AC clutch not engaging

Tags: honda, ac, hvac, fit

I have a 2007 Honda Fit. Two summers ago, my AC stopped working. I brought it to a shop, where the compressor was replaced. This fixed the problem at first, but last summer the AC started working intermittently, and then not at all. It's summer again, and I'm trying to solve this problem.

I'm not very knowledgeable about cars, but I've been reading and tinkering. I've discovered that the compressor clutch is not activating. I think the clutch itself is working, because I shorted the switch pins on the relay socket and heard it click. I also think the relays for the clutch and fans are working because I swapped them into the horn relay slot and the horn worked.

I've been reading all over that the car's computer could be inhibiting the clutch due to low refrigerant pressure. I bought a refrigerant refill kit, and attached it the low side and the needle jumped into the red zone indicating high pressure. I'm aware that the low side should have high pressure when the compressor is not running, but I'm guessing that this means I'm at least not *very* low on refrigerant. Am I wrong here?

Any other suggestions for things I could test?

Comment: The safest way of testing clutch coil operationality is checking for continuity at the clutch coil's terminals. As far as refrigerant is concerned, refrigerant pressure won't mean much because you could have the right pressure but not the right refrigerant quantity. The refrigerant filling kit is the wrong way to go. Your best option is having the system serviced by a licensed professional with a recovery machine, which will allow the system charge to be weighed and then correctly reinstated. Your problem could also be a faulty pressure switch. Unfortunately, AC diagnosis is hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the AC clutch wiring diagram, maybe this can help diagnose. As you can see it is controlled by the ECM/PCM and may be hard to diagnose on your own.

[image]